# Ampersand character in Office/Outlook Add-Ins

Tags: office365, manifest, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

There is a strange problem with Office365 Add-Ins. Add-in is described in manifest.xml file which is "linked" with some webpage.

Ok so lets skip to the problem.
In manifest.xml there is a tag

```
<DisplayName DefaultValue="SomethingAndSomething"/>
```

When I use ampersand in my name, like Something&Something it's not working.
My next try was to use HTML character code. So it looks like this

```
<DisplayName DefaultValue="Something&amp;Something"/>
```

Now it's working only for outlook website. It doesn't work for desktop. 
My Add-in should appears as button on ribbon, and there is no button in outlook desktop version.

**Edit:**
Ok I`ve got some new informations. I need to correct my question.

When I use single ampersand in  tag

```
&#38;
```

There is an underline in desktop version of outlook.
There is an ampersand in web version of outlook.

When I use two ampersands in  tag

```
&#38;&#38;
```

There is an ampersand in desktop version of outlook.
There is an double ampersand in web version of outlook.

Name of my product need to be also in GroupName (in ribbon), Label, description. So my string resources look like this

```
<bt:String id="myGroupLabel" DefaultValue="Something&#38;&#38;Something"/>
<bt:String id="myLabel" DefaultValue="Something&#38;&#38;Something"/>
<bt:String id="myTitle" DefaultValue="Something&#38;&#38;Something"/>
```

In this case when I use outlook desktop version, my ribbon button for Task Pane, doesn't show up. In web version everything works all right.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for sharing this question. Please try this one:

```js
&#38;&#38;
```

that should work.

Comment: It works for desktop! But now I've got two ampersands in my web version of outlook. Is there any way to set name according to platform?